Weighted Fourier multiplier in $L_w^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$
I'm studying Fourier multipliers. The definition is:
($1<p<\infty$) A essentially bounded function $m$ is a Fourier multiplier in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ if the map
\begin{align}  
L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)\to L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)\colon u\mapsto T(u)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(m\widehat{u}\right)
\end{align}
can be extended to an bounded operator on $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
In the case $p=2$, Plancherel's theorem implies that: a function $m$ is a Fourier multiplier in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ if and only if $m$ is essentially bounded.
Let $w$ a weight function i.e.  $w:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is a locally integrable and nonnegative function.
If we define the space
\begin{align}
L_w^2(\mathbb{R}^n)=\left\{u:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}\text{ measurable }\colon \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}w(x)|u(x)|^2\,dx<\infty\right\}
\end{align}
Another useful definition is: A weight $w$ belongs to the class $A_p$ (Muckenhoupt class) if
\begin{align}
    \sup_{B}\left(\frac{1}{|B|}\int_{B}w(x)\,dx\right)\left(\frac{1}{|B|}\int_{B}{w(x)}^{1/(1-p)}\,dx\right)^{p-1}<\infty
\end{align}
where $B$ is all ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Question. If $w$ is a Muckenhoupt weight $A_2$ and $m$ is a Fourier multiplier in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Then $m$ is a Fourier multiplier in $L_w^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$?
